# Comparing MATLAB AR model algorithms

Tags: matlab, statistics, modeling

I'm currently trying to build an AR model to approximate the error process in a sensor system. And I'm comparing the different parameter estimators in MATLAB. I have sets of data that i'm trying to match a model to, but I'm not too sure on the benefits/disadvantages of the algorithms available in the signal processing toolbox.

```
arburg: Autoregressive (AR) all-pole model parameters estimated using Burg method
arcov: Estimate AR model parameters using covariance method
armcov: Estimate AR model parameters using modified covariance method
aryule: Estimate autoregressive (AR) all-pole model using Yule-Walker method
```

If someone could give a more detailed description comparing the different algorithm and which one would best model existing data that would be very helpful.

Comment: If you follow the links on [this overview site](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/parametric-modeling.html) you find more information on the algorithms and examples for some of them.

Comment: yah, I did read through that, but that site only describes how each algorithm work (at least the parts that I understand), it doesn't answer which one is better for modeling existing data,